# I have trained a Forest model in SAS Model Studio. How do I apply it in SAS Studio?

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I have been using SAS Model Studio to train various models. For several models, including Linear Regression and Decision Tree models, there is a section of the output called 'Path EP Score Code'
that I can copy-paste into Model studio and apply to data as needed. This works just fine.

When I train a Forest model in SAS Model Studio, the same Path EP Score Code output is not available, and the code that *is* available in the output appears to make reference to model tables scored in CAS.

How can I take a model that is trained in SAS Model Studio, and apply it to data in SAS Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run it in SAS Studio via the downloaded file without publishing it to Model Manager:

1. Download the score code and save it somewhere on the server

[image]

2. Open SAS Studio
3. Start a CAS session
4. Load your astore file (you can get the file name from the notes in the downloaded code)
5. Run `proc astore` and point to your scoring file and loaded astore

Example:

```
cas;
caslib _ALL_ assign;

proc casutil incaslib='models' outcaslib='models';
    load casdata = '_56JR1BZ568NF5CSP46JF82HDC_ast.sashdat' 
         casout  = '_56JR1BZ568NF5CSP46JF82HDC_ast' 
         replace
    ;
quit;

proc astore;
    score data   = public.baseball
          rstore = models._56JR1BZ568NF5CSP46JF82HDC_ast
          epcode = '/path/to/score/code/on/server'
          out    = casuser.scored_data;
quit;
```

Comment: Adding a comment to note that this worked for me without the 'epcode...' line.